# Is there an adjective for acedia?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

The Oxford dictionary list "acedia" as:

> noun literary  another term for
>   accidie
>
> Origin: early 17th century: via late
>   Latin from Greek akēdia
>   'listlessness', from a- 'without' +
>   kēdos 'care'

Is there an adjective for being in a state of acedia?

Comment: Are you referring to one of the 7 Capital Sins?

Comment: Conceivably, I Googled for a word that met my feelings about a local election result.

Comment: Personally, I'd just make-up and use `acedic`.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that *acedia* is described by the NOAD as "spiritual or mental sloth, apathy," I would suggest *apathetic*, *indolent*, or *lazy*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the Capital Sin, Sloth. In such case I'd say **slothful**. There is also **sluggish** (it is given as a synonym of listless in the NOAD).

Acedia is the Latin form for "Sloth", in italian "Accidia". (I was able to recognise it for this reason.)

Comment: Isn't _slothfulness_ a noun?

Comment: Ops, I got confused :| Edited.

Comment: +1 @kiamlaluno What if they are too slothful to find out! :)

Comment: Believe it's a Cardinal Sin, not a Capital one.  (Though yes, I often find it capital, and yes, there was a scarlet-robed Cardinal Sin - in the Philippines, IIRC)

Comment: It's a Capital Sin, but in the Wiki page it gives Cardinal as a synonym, although I thought it wasn't the same thing... :|

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple synonyms, but not an adjective for ***acedia*** specifically.

> Zen
>
> Idyllic

Comment: Those words have strong positive acceptions, but acedia does not. In fact, it rather indicates *carelessness for life* and *apathy*.